# mariadb vs mysql * how both handle SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '[acs]%';

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When I run the following on MySql:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '[acs]%';
```

I get the expected results.

However, the same query on mariadb returns an empty set. Am I doing something wrong?

I've looked at the docs and it seems like they want it to be more like

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City RLIKE '(a|c|s)'.
```

Is there a command that will work on both? Should I use REGEXP?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City REGEXP 'a|c|s'
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: Have you tried if `REGEXP` works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can you the [REGEXP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp/) function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City REGEXP '[acs]'
```

Comment: Needs `^` to anchor at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that this query returns results on MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[acs]%';
```

Why?  No city names that I know of have the character `'['`.  And, if they did, it seems even less likely that they would have the character `']'`.

You may be confusing MySQL with SQL Server.  The latter has extended `LIKE` patterns to include character classes.  The equivalent logic in MySQL is:

```
WHERE City REGEXP '^[acs]'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
WHERE LEFT(City, 1) IN ('a', 'c', 's')
```